# $u\in H^{1}_{0}$ and $\Delta u=1$ on $\Omega= (0,1)\times(0,1)$ then $u\notin C^{2}(\overline{\Omega})$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am stuck with the following question:

Let $\Omega:=(0,1)\times (0,1)$ and let $u\in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ satisfying $\Delta u=1$. Prove that $u\notin C^{2}(\overline{\Omega})$. Determine the best possible regularity of $u$ on $\Omega$ or $\overline{\Omega}$, for example, find  the greatest number $s$ such that $u\in H^{s}(\Omega)$.

My vague attempt: I think first I will try to find a special solution and then turn to the Laplacian equation with $0$ on the right hand side.

Comment: What does $H_0^1$ mean? Zero boundary conditions?

Comment: $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $H^{1}(\Omega)$ with respect to the norm of $H^{1}(\Omega)$. The equation $\Delta u=1$ is understood as $$-\int_{\Omega} \nabla u\nabla \varphi =\int_{\Omega}\varphi,\forall \varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega).$$

Comment: Checking $u \not\in C^2(\bar\Omega)$ should be easy: If you assume $u \in C^2(\bar\Omega)$, you would have $\Delta u(0,0) = 0$ (differentiate along the boundary). However, this is a contradiction to the continuity of $\Delta u$ and $\Delta u = 1$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: @gerw Your answer is very interesting.

Comment: @gerw If I change $\Omega$ to a smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, do you think any solution $u\in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ to the equation $\Delta u=1$ should always be in $C^{2}(\overline{\Omega})$?

Comment: @JohnHana: Yes, this is a classical result.